# I don't know if my question belongs to worldbuilding or writers SE

Tags: support

Exactly as the title says.

The question is: "Could creating my own flora/fauna impact the popularity of my work by distancing readers?".

As the question adresses both worldbuilding and writing technique I'm not sure where it belongs to. Also, if I have this kind of doubt in the future can I simply make the question and wait for it to be moved if I got it wrong?

Comment: That's quite an edge case and would probably depend on how you ask the question. Try posting a draft in the [question sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)!

Comment: @PatJ Ooh, great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed @Patj advice and posted on Sandbox. There, people told me that it would probably be a better fit for Writers SE. So I changed the question completely and here it is:

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/26482/how-to-introduce-alien-flora-fauna-without-turning-the-fiction-into-a-biology-bo

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

PatJ is right, posting the question to the sandbox as you did https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4362/49 is a good way to handle this.

Alternatively posting your full question here would allow people to give more detailed feedback than there is room for in the sandbox format.